# First Year Anniversary Next Month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a SQl comand without success:

```
WITH `params` AS (
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS `nextmonth`
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `params` CROSS JOIN `Subscribers`
WHERE MONTH(`start_date`) = MONTH(`nextmonth`) AND
YEAR(`start_date`) = YEAR(`nextmonth`) - 1
```

It aims to get First Year Anniversary Next Month of a customer. But instead I get a syntax error.

Would a good soul help me to find out where I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the syntax error.

Comment: Hi Felix, the error is : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`params` AS (
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS `nextmonth`
)
SE' at line 1

Comment: First thought, don't use backticks (`).  Use normal single quotes.

Comment: I am using mysqladmin so the backticks (`) are the way to do it. Normal single quotes give error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion... write your predicates to reference the "bare column" start_date from the Subscribers table.

And use expressions to get the lower and upper bounds for the start_date of the subscribers you want to return.

Suppose "next month" is May 2016.

The subscribers that will have a 1 year anniversary date next month are the subscribers who had a start_date in May of 2015.

The example query is returning COUNT(*). I suggest that for developing the query and testing, we might want to return the start_date from each subscriber to verify we're getting the correct result.

I'd write the query in this form:

```
 SELECT s.*
   FROM `Subscribers` s
  WHERE s.start_date >=  dateexpr1 
    AND s.end_date   <   dateexpr2
```

For dateexpr1, I'd use something like

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -11 MONTH
```

And for datexpr2, I'd use

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -10 MONTH
```

We can test those expressions...

```
SELECT NOW()
     , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -11 MONTH AS lb
     , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -10 MONTH AS ub
```

returns:

```
NOW()                lb          ub          
-------------------  ----------  ----------
2016-04-20 23:54:32  2015-05-01  2015-06-01
```

If this month is April 2016, then next month is May 2016. Won't all of the subscribers that have a "One Year Anniversary Next Month" have a start_date sometime in May 2015?

```
 SELECT s.*
   FROM `Subscribers` s
  WHERE s.start_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -11 MONTH
    AND s.start_date <  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -10 MONTH
```

That's how I would do it.

In terms of MySQL performance, this pattern (using predicates with bare columns) will enable MySQL to make effective use of a range scan operation on an index which has start_date as the leading column.

If we want to move those messy expressions to an inline view, we could do something like this:

```
 SELECT s.*
   FROM ( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') + INTERVAL -11 MONTH AS lb
        ) p
   JOIN `Subscribers` s
     ON s.start_date >= p.lb
    AND s.start_date <  p.lb + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Comment: Hi Spencer, it worked ! ! It is an amazing solution. Thanks a lot , you have no idea how you helped me ! Rgds

Comment: My apologies to the "try this" enthusiasts. My goal was to shed some insight about our approach to solving problems using SQL, and MySQL in particular. The syntax error you were running into... MySQL doesn't support Common Table Expressions (CTE). It does support inline views (or, "derived tables" in the MySQL vernacular) which aren't nearly as powerful. But they are suitable for some applications.

Comment: One thing...how can a make a count on this expression ?

Comment: Just replace this: " **SELECT s.*** " with this: " **SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt** ".  For testing, you may want to also include  MIN(s.start_date) and MAX(s.start_date) in the SELECT list along with the count... verify that the earliest date and latest date are in the range you are expecting.

Comment: OK spencer. Thanks a lot again. I learned a lot from you today. rgds

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 'params' AS (
SELECT MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GetDate()) AS 'nextmonth'
,YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, GetDate()) AS 'nextyear'
)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `params` CROSS JOIN `Subscribers`
WHERE MONTH(`start_date`) = 'nextmonth' AND
YEAR(`start_date`) = 'nextyear'
```

I am assuming your 'start_date' is the field for the anniversary date.

Comment: Yes, the date information is in the field 'start_date' but I want to calculate the anniversary based on this

Comment: MySQL doesn't support Common Table Expressions. And in MySQL, single quotes enclose string literals, not identifiers. And GetDate() isn't a valid MySQL function. For performance, since MySQL doesn't allow us to create function based indexes, we prefer to use predicates on "bare" columns.